# Axes not showing in D3 diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, heatmap, diagram

I'm trying to create a heat map.
The code is on Codepen: https://codepen.io/imestin/pen/qBOpodX?editors=1010

My problem is, that the axes are not showing on the SVG canvas.
Inspecting it with web developer tools, I can see the  elements.

These are the lines that I think are important in drawing the axes (for the x-axis):

```
    let minYear = d3.min(data, d => d.year );
    let maxYear = d3.max(data, d => d.year );
    let xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                 .domain(minYear,maxYear)
                 .range(0,canvasX);

   //xAxis - needs xScale
   let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

   //X-axis draw
   Canvas.append("g")
    .attr("id","x-axis")
    .attr("class","tick")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (edge) + ", " + (canvasY) + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
```

Other elements are drawing correctly, basic SVG drawing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xScale domain and range need an array of values, for example:

```
xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([minYear,maxYear])
.range([0,canvasX]);
```

And secondly, the axis is positioned off the bottom of canvas, so it needs to adjusted up, for example:

```
Canvas.append("g")
.attr("id","x-axis")
.attr("class","tick")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + (edge) + ", " + (canvasY - 20) + ")")
.call(xAxis)
```

Comment: yes! this solved the problem. thank you for your help!